# Unable to pass values in database

Tags: android

Below is the java code for sending data to MySQl database in localhost server. The
scripted language used is php. Php code is working fine and values get inserted when i
use it through a browser. I feel there is error in communication. But i am unable to
debug it. please help.

```
    package com.example.databasetest1;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button Enter;
    EditText tName;
    String sName;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEnter);
            tName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
            sName=tName.getText().toString();
            Enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new         DefaultHttpClient();
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",sName));
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.173.1/try_database/name_insert.php");
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

        }
        /*public void insert() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",sName));
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.173.1/try_database/name_insert.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            httpClient.execute(httpPost);
}*/

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask to establish a connection.

Comment: `I feel there is error in communication`. If any error occur please post the error don't feel

Comment: I will move the code to async and tell u gus what happened. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) tutorial on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com). Clearly explained how to perform Network related operations using the class `AsyncTask`.

You may also take a look at:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/

Check out this:

[When, why and how to use async task ?](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the n/w i/o on UI thread which is not allowed. Do it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `Network` executions on `UIThread` which will give you exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in post-Gingerbread devices. You need to move your `onClick`code into an `AsyncTask`